# Status code 304 (Jade, Node, Express)

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, pug

I'm linking bootstrap and jquery in my jade file,

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.css')
```

and

```
script(src='/javascripts/jquery-3.1.1.js')
script(src='/javascripts/bootstrap.js')
```

This Jade file is in my views folder. 
The boostrap css is in my public/stylesheets folder and the javascript is in the public/javascripts folder.

When I run my application using nodemon, it says

```
GET / 200 80ms - 1.65kb
GET /stylesheets/bootstrap.css 304 1ms
GET /javascripts/jquery-3.1.1.js 304 3
GET /javascripts/bootstrap.js 304 2ms
```

The javascript and css files do not load up.

Suggestions?

Comment: 304 response indicates that the resource has not been modified. What is wrong with that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**304 Not Modified**

> If the client has performed a conditional GET request and access is
>   allowed, but the document has not been modified, the server SHOULD
>   respond with this status code. The 304 response MUST NOT contain a
>   message-body, and thus is always terminated by the first empty line
>   after the header fields.

Server sent `304` `http` status to the client (browser) to let it know the file is not modified since the browser last received the copy of the file with `200` status code. When this happens, usually browser should have `cached copy` of the files and will load the same from the `cache`.

Better, clear all your browser `cache` by deleting all temporary files, histories etc and close and reopen (restart) your browser.

Reload the page and check the status code again in `nodemon`. It should be `200` this time.

Comment: This makes sense. However, I'm still confused as to why the css and js files won't load in the browser. If they are cached, shouldn't they be working?

Comment: Yes they should be loaded from the cache. Please try clearing the cache.

Answer (score 3):

To get rid of this status completely you can add header

res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate')