# reactjs bootstrap IE - App is not aligning like it does in chrome / Firefox

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, bootstrap-4, alignment, react-bootstrap

I built a reactjs app but when browsing to it in IE all the content is squished in the middle of the page ... Chrome / Firefox / Edge is all fine but in IE its like it  is not picking up the bootstrap pieces

Here is my index.html

```
<html lang="en-US">

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="//cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Can you spy the network tab to see if the call to load bootstrap files is successful or not.

Comment: seems to be throwing a 304 error when trying to load https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css & https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css

Answer (score 0):

**304 Not Modified**

> The HTTP 304 Not Modified client redirection response code indicates that there is no need to retransmit the requested resources. It is an implicit redirection to a cached resource. This happens when the request method is safe, like a GET or a HEAD request, or when the request is conditional and uses a If-None-Match or a If-Modified-Since header.

Easily say it means that files was not modified since last load and browser can use it from local cache.

I suggest that you could clear your browser's cache by deleting all temporary files, histories and so on.Then close the browser and try to reopen your browser.

Reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40583045/10487763

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/304

Comment: You may try the steps in this link: https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=15141

Comment: No i need to do it at the server level

Comment: I suggest you may try to download the css and js file to local and rename the file.Then you add the file to your project to see if it works.